# SQL- sequential month macro with multiple loops

Tags: sql, macros, sas

I am trying to join 12 monthly data on a sequential declining basis into a single table. The monthly data join will look at a declining sequence. However I am struggling to come up with a logic to develop multiple macros to run this.
The month is in a YYYYMM format.

The code 
`

```
    PROC SQL;
       CREATE TABLE WANT_YYYYMM AS /* I want the tables on monthly but incremental sequence basis. 
For e.g monthly data for 201612 will join with 201701,201702....201711....
monthly data for 201701 will join with 201702,201703....201711 and so on.*/
       SELECT (COUNT(A.canc_accts)) AS canc_accts_n, 
              (COUNT(A.canc_accts)) AS canc_accts_n+1,
              (COUNT(A.canc_accts)) AS canc_accts_n+2,
              ........
              (COUNT(A.canc_accts)) AS canc_accts_n+11          

    FROM HAVEDATA_YYYYMM A
     LEFT JOIN HAVE_DATA_YYYYMM+1 B ON (A.ACCT_NO= B.ACCT_NO)
     LEFT JOIN HAVE_DATA_YYYYMM+2 C ON (A.ACCT_NO= B.ACCT_NO)
     LEFT JOIN HAVE_DATA_YYYYMM+3 D ON (A.ACCT_NO= B.ACCT_NO)
     ........
     LEFT JOIN HAVE_DATA_YYYYMM+11 G ON (A.ACCT_NO= B.ACCT_NO)
     GROUP BY A.Fees;
    QUIT;
```

`
The data for table YYYYMMM should look like this

```
            canc_n   canc_n+1  canc_n+2......  canc_n+10  canc_n+11

201612        200     225       250               325       350
201701        222     240       277               312        -
201702        210     232       234                 -
.
.
201711        200      -         -
```

Need some help on running a macro loop for the month and the canc_n variable. Any help in building multiple macros or any logic to build this will be appreciated.

Comment: Why SQL and not data step?

Comment: Why are you counting the same thing? Should that be COUNT(B....) , COUNT(C....) ?

Comment: Do you really have multiple datasets named with different *YYYYMM* suffixes? Or is there a field in one dataset of *YYYYMM*. Hoping for the latter as with the former, SQL being a declarative language cannot determine logic on names of identifiers like table names only data within contained fields.

Comment: I don't understand. You have one table HAVE_DATA_YYYYMM? It has a month column which is a string formatted 'YYYYMM'? And a column acct_no? And both columns together are the table's primary key? And there is a third column canc_accts holding a value? And you want to present the data in a grid with one row per start month and columns representing the start month till start month + 11? And the values shown are the sums of canc_accts per month? Then shouldn't canc_n+1 for 201612 be the same value as canc_n for 201701, because both are the sums for January 2017?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be easy to do with a macro.  To make it easier to generate date like strings you can use date manipulation functions like `intnx()`.

```
%macro codegen(yymm);
%local month i ;
%let month=%sysfunc(inputn(&yymm.01,yymmdd8));
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE WANT_%sysfunc(intnx(month,&month,0),yymmn6) AS 
  SELECT COUNT(A.canc_accts) AS canc_accts_0
%do i=1 %to 12 ;
   ,COUNT(x&i..canc_accts) AS canc_accts_&i
%end;
  FROM HAVE_DATA_%sysfunc(intnx(month,&month,0),yymmn6) A
%do i=1 %to 12 ;
  LEFT JOIN HAVE_DATA_%sysfunc(intnx(month,&month,&i),yymmn6) x&i
    ON (A.ACCT_NO= x&i..ACCT_NO)
%end;
  GROUP BY A.Fees
;
QUIT;
%mend codegen ;
```

So if I call that macro with the value `201605` it will generate this SQL query.

```
CREATE TABLE WANT_201605 AS 
SELECT
  COUNT(A.canc_accts) AS canc_accts_0
 ,COUNT(x1.canc_accts) AS canc_accts_1 
 ,COUNT(x2.canc_accts) AS canc_accts_2 
 ,COUNT(x3.canc_accts) AS canc_accts_3 
 ,COUNT(x4.canc_accts) AS canc_accts_4 
 ,COUNT(x5.canc_accts) AS canc_accts_5 
 ,COUNT(x6.canc_accts) AS canc_accts_6 
 ,COUNT(x7.canc_accts) AS canc_accts_7 
 ,COUNT(x8.canc_accts) AS canc_accts_8 
 ,COUNT(x9.canc_accts) AS canc_accts_9 
 ,COUNT(x10.canc_accts) AS canc_accts_10 
 ,COUNT(x11.canc_accts) AS canc_accts_11 
 ,COUNT(x12.canc_accts) AS canc_accts_12 
FROM HAVE_DATA_201605 A
 LEFT JOIN HAVE_DATA_201606 x1 ON (A.ACCT_NO= x1.ACCT_NO) 
 LEFT JOIN HAVE_DATA_201607 x2 ON (A.ACCT_NO= x2.ACCT_NO) 
 LEFT JOIN HAVE_DATA_201608 x3 ON (A.ACCT_NO= x3.ACCT_NO) 
 LEFT JOIN HAVE_DATA_201609 x4 ON (A.ACCT_NO= x4.ACCT_NO) 
 LEFT JOIN HAVE_DATA_201610 x5 ON (A.ACCT_NO= x5.ACCT_NO) 
 LEFT JOIN HAVE_DATA_201611 x6 ON (A.ACCT_NO= x6.ACCT_NO) 
 LEFT JOIN HAVE_DATA_201612 x7 ON (A.ACCT_NO= x7.ACCT_NO) 
 LEFT JOIN HAVE_DATA_201701 x8 ON (A.ACCT_NO= x8.ACCT_NO) 
 LEFT JOIN HAVE_DATA_201702 x9 ON (A.ACCT_NO= x9.ACCT_NO) 
 LEFT JOIN HAVE_DATA_201703 x10 ON (A.ACCT_NO= x10.ACCT_NO) 
 LEFT JOIN HAVE_DATA_201704 x11 ON (A.ACCT_NO= x11.ACCT_NO) 
 LEFT JOIN HAVE_DATA_201705 x12 ON (A.ACCT_NO= x12.ACCT_NO) 
GROUP BY A.Fees 
;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom. This is really helpful . I have another leading question based on your code. Do I run another macro if I need multiple tables ?... like in the above example the table is for 201605, however I need to run for subsequent months (201606,201607 etc..)

Comment: To run a macro you call it by name and supply values for its parameters.  There are many ways to generate multiple calls to the macro. You could just repeat the calls yourself. `%codegen(201605); %codegen(201606);`  Or create another macro that generates multiple calls to this macro. Or generate the calls from a data step using `call execute()`. Or you could change the macro to add another loop so that it can make multiple datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Use macro to stack all your data.  The stacker will add a new categorical variable "source".  Then do your count / pivot transform on the stack.

```
data have_201701;
   account = 1;
   fee = 'revert';
run;

%macro stack (out=, base=, from=, months=12);
    %local i ym ymf;

    %let ym = %sysfunc(inputn(&from,yymmn6));

    data &out / view=&out;
      set
         %do i = 1 %to &months; 

           %let ymf = %sysfunc(putn(&ym,yymmn6));
           &base.&ymf

           %let ym = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&ym,1));

         %end;             
         indsname = _source_
      ;
      source = _source_;
    run;
%mend;

options nodsnferr; * do not cause an error if the there is a request for a data set that is not found;

options mprint; * logging purposes only;
%stack (out=tall, base=have_, from=201612);
options nomprint;

* Now deal with one or two data transformation steps based on "tall" and new categorical variable "source" ;
```

You can pivot with SQL + TRANPOSE, TABULATE, REPORT, HASH, or ARRAY.

The original question was not clear enough to indicate the counting requirements, especially when showing join by account and group by fees and not maintaining those features in the wanted output.